# C language. Factorial code (shortest possible)

Tags: c

I wanted to code the shortest snippet possible for a factorial operation, using also the minimum number of variables (could not make it with less than 2) and the minimum of lines too. But, it is not working despite that the logic is, I think, good and correct, :/

Here it is: say factorial of 5.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()   
int x, i = 5;
{
     while(i!=1)
     {
         i--;
         x *= i;
     }

     printf("%d",x); 
}
```

So, let's depict what that code would do:

inside the loop `i` turns 4,
then we have `x = 5 * 4` which makes it 20.

Next round `i` is 3, we have

```
x = 20 * 3
```

Next round `i` is 2

```
x = 60 * 2
```

next `i` is 1   `x = 120 * 1`, so that is the factorial.

I know there are bright brains out there who can come up with obfuscated code to do all that in half a line, but I would be satisfied just to find out why is giving me errors.

UPDATE AFTER PEOPLE'S INPUT:

it always yields 0 now, even if I change i!=2

```
     main()
     {
        int x, i = 5;
        while(i!=1)
       {
         i--;
         x *= i;
       }

    printf("%d",x);


   }
```

THE FINAL SOLUTION AND EXPLANATION:

I code in PHP and Java and today I wanted to do a quicky in C, so when I wrote this:

int x, i = 5;

I took for granted that it would initialize both to 5, as it does in PHP and JAVA, but it does not!

So, if I do

```
 #include<stdio.h>

main()   
int x = 5;
int i = 5;
{
     while(i!=1)
     {
         i--;
         x *= i;
     }

     printf("%d",x); 
     return (0);
}
```

my code works.

Thank you to all those who pointed the fundamental syntax errors.

Syntax errors happen when one is not familiar with the language rules, but the most important is the logic of the code and that was correct.

Comment: Post actual code that will compile. Copy-pase it, don't write it here on the board. Indent the code.

Comment: Check your brace placement.

Comment: @Lundin I think that is the actual code, which is why there are errors.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Aha. I stopped reading when I saw the unindented mess with utterly fundamental syntax errors.

Comment: braces and syntax if you want yes, but can you devise it shorter than the 2 lines I came up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `{` and also you need to initialize `x` before using as it causing **undefined behavior**.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1, i = 5;
    while(i!=1)
    {
       x *= i;
       i--;
    }
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initialize x? hold on a second, you mean that when I did int x, y = 5; that does not initialize both of them?  Sorry about this, but since I always code in PHP and Java I took that it would initialize both. thank you

Comment: It 'created' the variable but it has no value until you assign one (i.e. initialize it).

Comment: @user191282: In C, you have to initialize all variables explicitly. Even in Java, a declaration such as int x, y = 5 causes x to be zero and y to be 5.

Answer (score 5):

By forgetting a `{` after `main()` you have fooled the compiler into believing you intended to write K&R C, so it started interpreting your locals as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the *shortest* code possible, here is an analytic solution not requiring any variables. It doesn't use any sort of loop or recursion.

```
long int fac(unsigned long int n) {
    return lround(exp(lgamma(n+1)));
}
```

Note that you must include `math.h` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x, i = 5;
```

The above line should come inside main after the `{`. In your case, it comes between `main()` and `{`

Answer (score 1):

Ps yo encontré otra más corta, weyes:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int fac=5,i=fac;
        while(i>1){
            i--;
            fac=i*fac;
     }
    printf("%d",fac);
    }
```

Comment: In english, please.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize x = 1

Hopefully this will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to Perform factorial...

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
  int num = 5, sum = num;
  while(num > 1)
  {
     sum *= (--num);
  }
  printf("%d",sum);
}
```